# I add some code in aplication.css. Why it disappear after restart server by foreman start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I add in aplication.css

```
*= require rouge
#search {
  position:absolute; left:80px; top:20px;
}
```

After restart server by foreman start, this code disappear. Why?